# How to make the entire 'REQUEST_URI' go to a parameter

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, parameters

I'm using Apache rewrite_mod to have all test after the URL adress go into parameter text using the following in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?text=$1 [L,QSA]
```

which works if I have `www.example.com/some_text`
but doesn't when I have `www.example.com/some_text/some other text`

I want to have in the text parameter the whole request: "some_text/some other text"
not only "some other text".

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd let apache/php sort this out:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

PHP stores all info you may need in $_SERVER

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']   // Original uri with original query string
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING'] // Original query string
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']  // Original uri without query string
```

This method will leave $_GET / $_POST / $_REQUEST etc. in tact.

Comment: Good point, they are identical. (Although i believed the REDIRECT_ version to contain the original one, but it doesn't.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this and it works perfectly:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` will contain the query string.